# Eigenvector of product of commuting matricies

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be commuting $n\times n$ matricies over an algebraically closed field and let $v$ be an eigenvector of $AB=BA$, i.e. there exists a scalar $\lambda$ such that
$$ABv=\lambda v$$

Is $v$ necessarily an eigenvector of both $A$ and $B$? What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $A$, $B$ for this to be true?

Edit: If $A$ and $B$ are both diagonalizable then it is obviously true

Comment: what are your ideas and attempts about this question?

Comment: There are some simple counterexamples, for example let $R$ be the $90^\circ$ degree rotation matrix in the plane. Then every vector is an eigenvector of $R R^{-1} = 1$, but $R$ and $R^{-1}$ have no eigenvectors.

Comment: @Joppy Thanks. I've updated the question to specifically about algebraically closed fields (in which case your $R$ and $R^{-1}$ do have eigenvectors over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: You can still use the counterexample by @Joppy. Just take any vector $v\ne 0$ which is not an eigenvector of $R$ (or $R^{-1}$), it will still be an eigenvector of $RR^{-1}$.

Comment: There are still many counterexamples. For example, let $P_1 = \mathrm{diag}(1, 0)$ and $P_2 = \mathrm{diag}(0, 1)$. Then $P_1$ and $P_2$ commute, and $P_1 P_2 = 0$ has a two-dimensional eigenspace, but each of $P_1$ and $P_2$ have two one-dimensional eigenspaces.

Comment: Thanks to you both!