# Eigenvector of sum and product of commuting matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Update to my question here
[Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445810/eigenvector-of-product-of-commuting-matricies?noredirect=1#comment5052498_2445810)

Consider the field $\mathbb{C}$ with operators $A,B:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$, $n$ finite, with $AB=BA$, i.e. $A$ and $B$ commute. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $AB$ and $A+B$ with eigenvalues of the following form 
$$
(A+B)v=(x+y)v, \ (AB)v=(xy)v
$$
with both $x$ and $y$ non-zero, $x+y\neq 0$ and $xy\neq 0$.

Given these conditions (which are more restricting than the ones in my previous question), is $v$ and eigenvector of $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $A(x,y)=(2x,y)$, $B(x,y)=(x,2y)$, $x=1$, $y=2$ and $v=(1,1)$. Then$$(A+B)v=3v=(x+y)v\text{ and }(AB)v=2v=(xy)v,$$but $v$ is *not* an eigenvector of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to include that also $xy\neq 0$.

Comment: @Okazaki I've edited my answer.